# how to send remote notification in nativescript

Tags: android, nativescript, android-notifications, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-plugin

We have a requirement to send notification to the Mobile App Users on periodic basis. (Say Every day morning 6 AM). We are using Nativescript to develop the Mobile Application. 
Can someone help to confirm if this can be achieved? if yes, Any sample code/plugin/directions will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it from within your app, this might help (not using myself)
https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-local-notifications

Another solution could be to generate scheduled notifications from your server and push them to your app via FCM. In which case you could use this plugin https://github.com/NativeScript/push-plugin (I'm using this)

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, possible. Checkout the [nativescript-plugin-firebase](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/master/docs/MESSAGING.md) or [nativescript-push](https://github.com/NativeScript/push-plugin). You will have all the details documented in the ReadMe along with sample code.

You might setup a job in your server which would fetch all the list of users and their device tokens you want to send push notification to, pass it on to FCM.

Comment: hi Manoj, can you kindly look at this problem in the below link ....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54364402/step-by-step-implementation-of-nativescript-push-notification-in-nativescript