# step by step implementation of nativescript push notification in nativescript

Tags: firebase, notifications, push, nativescript

can anyone give step by step guidence starting from creating a helloworld app then the remaining steps to do push notifications.
i have already gone through the below link and failed to achieve that
https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase

i have some progress on it, refer below code.

```
http.request({
        url: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
        method: "POST",
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'key=AIzaSyBri16HAa7g2REEy******YFnTDGIlM_1k', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        content: JSON.stringify({
          "notification": {
            "title": "testingtesting",
            "text": "some text",
            "sound": "default",
            "click_action": "GENERAL",
            "badge": "1",
            "showWhenInForeground": true
          },
          "content_available": false,
          "data": {
            "foo": "bar"
          },
          "priority": "High",
          'to': "AAAACcS8hG0:APA91bEonX87xRfBHvccNheOR2ppFHZKaFlGGm6PRF6eEEYZg5Gd7uU_OU0GRJ0MkiTrR2gSDGO7Nz6BByujX4ex1jGgKpO20SXcGMa78k405vNV_4uJ1UDk_b-0-regi5x96KRcaOMH"
        })
      }).then((response) => {
        //HttpResult = response.content.toJSON();
        console.log('----------------------------------------------------');
        console.log(response);
      }, (e) => {
        console.log("Error occurred " + JSON.stringify(e));
      });
    },
```

the response is as below.

```
JS: ----------------------------------------------------
JS: {
JS:   "content": {
JS:     "multicast_id": 5720873045813109000,
JS:     "success": 1,
JS:     "failure": 0,
JS:     "canonical_ids": 0,
JS:     "results": [
JS:       {
JS:         "message_id": "0:1548488437363910%0000000000000000"
JS:       }
JS:     ]
JS:   },
JS:   "statusCode": 200,
JS:   "headers": {
JS:     "null": "HTTP/1.1 200 OK",
JS:     "Alt-Svc": "quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"44,43,39\"",
JS:     "Cache-Control": "private, max-age=0",
JS:     "Content-Encoding": "gzip",
JS:     "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
JS:     "Date": "Sat, 26 Jan 2019 07:40:37 GMT",
JS:     "Expires": "Sat, 26 Jan 2019 07:40:37 GMT",
JS:     "Server": "GSE",
JS:     "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
JS:     "X-Android-Received-Millis": "1548488436596",
JS:     "X-Android-Response-Source": "NETWORK 200",
JS:     "X-Android-Selected-Protocol": "http/1.1",
JS:     "X-Android-Sent-Millis": "1548488436437",
JS:     "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
JS:     "X-Frame-Options": "SAMEORIGIN",
JS:     "X-XSS-Protection": "1; mode=block"
JS:   }
JS: }
```

even it says success. i have not got any notification on android. i'm not using ios.

Comment: the thing i'm not getting is how my app receive push notification. and where i need to write that code in my app. whether in app.js or somewhere else and what code i need to write there to receive notification. wheather it will work on background or not ???

Comment: what is your issue? are you getting errors when you run the app?

Comment: You can see the demo app for the plugin.

Comment: @mast3rd3mon no im receiving notification. but i dont know how to send t through http service from app. the only thing currently im doing is from firebase console i write message and then ill send notification to my app.

Comment: @vikasacharya are you receiving push notifications, when sent from Firebase console?

Comment: @saibbyweb  yes im getting.

Answer (score -2):

I am fairly new here, but I realized you are much more likely to get a solution to your problem if you post your Nativescript code here, along with your questions. That way, we can look to see where your code is failing. Regarding this plugin, I will tell you it is *imperative* you follow every step in the [readme](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-push-notifications#installation) file that comes with the plugin. I also had a heck of a time getting this to work, but now I have push notifications working.

Here is an example of NativeScript push notifications in action. This app will also teach you how they achieved their Push Notifications. These are the nicest Push Notifications I have run across yet.  [NativeScript Push Notification Examples](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.nativescript.pluginshowcase)

Please post your page XML and js code-behind, and we'll have a look. Also be sure this value is set properly, as this caused me a headache. Good luck, post your code so we can help!

**Tip: Make sure your project number exactly matched your Firebase project value.**

```
var pushSettings = {
        senderID: "<ENTER_YOUR_PROJECT_NUMBER>", // Required: setting with the sender/project number
        notificationCallbackAndroid: function (stringifiedData, fcmNotification) {
            var notificationBody = fcmNotification && fcmNotification.getBody();
            _this.updateMessage("Message received!\n" + notificationBody + "\n" + stringifiedData);
        }
    };
```

Comment: i have updated the code and result in my question. now the problem is the response was success and i havn't got any notification. can you please confirm me if push notification works only for ios. because eddy has mentioned in his github readme that active push notifications only for ios.

Comment: right now i am creating and sending notification from firebase console cloud messaging tab. ill set instant and compose message and sending notifications. but i want to send it through my admin app.